# Test for a specific text format in a text area

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing some javascript to validate user input in a text area.  Here are the requirements for input format:

1. Input must be in the format of two hex values separated by a space (i.e. A7 B3 9D).
2. Input must be valid hex values.

I have requirement #2 sorted out with a regExpression `valueOne.match("[0-9A-Fa-f]{1}")` (or at least I hope that is the recommended way to do it).  So I am just looking for some input on how to go about handling requirement number one in a simple and efficient way.

Thanks!

Comment: _"must be in the format of two hex values separated by a space"_ - But your example is _three_ hex values separated by spaces. Do you mean groups of two hex _digits_ separated by spaces?

Comment: my appologies for the confusion, it can be as many pairs of hex values as the user wants, but they must all be separated by a space.  Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @nnnnnn I think he means a sequence of two hex chars separated by space. In effect, it should describe a sequence of bytes in hex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This regex will do it:

```
/^[0-9A-F]{2}(\s[0-9A-F]{2})*$/i
```

That is:

```
^                // beginning of string
[0-9A-F]{2}      // two characters of 0-9 or A-F
(\s[0-9A-F]{2})* // zero or more instances of a space followed by
                 // two characters of 0-9 or A-F
$                // end of string
```

Where the `i` flag at the end makes it case insensitive.

To use it:

```
 var valueOne = // set to your textarea's value here
 if (/^[0-9A-F]{2}(\s[0-9A-F]{2})*$/i.test(valueOne)) {
     // is OK, do something
 } else {
     // is not OK, do something
 }
```

Comment: @nmenego - Sorry, I initially had `A-Z` but then immediately realised my mistake and changed it to `A-F`...

Comment: Your description says it will check for two valid hex values separated by zero or more instances of a space then for two characters of valid hex values and that is the end of the string?  I am a little confused by that "end of string" line, will that check for as many hex pairs as are in the text area or will it only check for two pairs then end the string?  Also, is there any way to specifically check for one space only in between the pairs?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: The `*` in this part of the expression: `(\s[0-9A-F]{2})*` means the part inside the parentheses will be matched zero or more times with no upper limit on the number of matches. So that part would match `" AA"` or `" AA BB"` or `" AA BB CC DD EE FF 11 4F"` (etc.). The `$` to match the end of string is to make sure there are not _other_ characters between the last valid two-digit hex number and the end of string. `\s` matches a single white-space character, but note that that also matches tabs and so forth - to match _only_ space characters use `/^[0-9A-F]{2}( [0-9A-F]{2})*$/i`. Try it...