# Test for invalid text format in text area

Tags: javascript, regex, arrays

A continuation of my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12362160/test-for-a-specific-text-format-in-a-text-area/12362205#12362205)...

After testing the text format, if it is not the correct format I would like to figure out which pairs of hex values are incorrect (i.e. any pair that contains value(s) other than[0-9A-Fa-f]).

```
if( validFormat ) {
// do processing
}
else {
// find invalid hex value pairs
}
```

What is the most efficient way to obtain a list of incorrect(invalid) hex pairs so that I can report back the errors and their associated hex pairs.

**Edit for additional question**

Also, how would I go about testing to ensure there is not a "double space" anywhere, because that also constitutes for invalid format even though the hex pairs may be valid.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest is to find all values and scan for those that are not valid:

```
var isHexPair = /^[0-9a-f]{2}$/i;
var allPairs = myTextArea.value.split(/\s+/);
var notHex   = [];
for (var i=allPairs.length;i--;){
  if (!isHexPair.test(allPairs[i])){
    notHex.push(allPairs(i));
  }
}
```

That regex says:

- `^` starting at the beginning of the string
- `[0-9a-f]` find any character that is a digit or a-f
- `{2}` find exactly two of them
- `$` making sure that we are now at the end of the string
- `i` and make it case-insensitive (allow A-F as well as a-f)

With the above you can then do:

```
if (notHex.length){
  // There is at least one invalid entry
}else{
  // all is well
}
```

---

**Edit**: If you explicitly want to test that the string contains nothing but single-byte hex strings separated by a single space, the simplest test would just be:

```
if (/^([0-9a-f]{2} )+[0-9a-f]{2}$/i.test(myStr)){ /* valid! */ }
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you!  Can you also take a look at my edit above and help me out with the double space issue?  Thanks!

Comment: To check for the presence of a double space, simply `if (myStr.indexOf('  ')!=-1){ ... }`; if you want to check for multiple whitespace of any kind (e.g. a space and a tab, or two newlines) then `if (/\s{2,}/.test(myStr)){ /* 2 or more whitespace in a row */ }`

Answer (score 0):

Take the values of the text area and store in a `var` since they are space separated do a `.splt(" ")` (splits on white space) on it and you will end up with an array of hex pairs. Then just iterate through the array comparing inside your loop to the regex from your last question, and store the invalid pairs in a new `var` and print that out to the user.